# what are differences and processes of Md5 , blowfish, and twofish encryption algorithms

Tags: encryption

i have been wondering and surfing the net on the differences and processes of Md5, blowfish and twofish encryption algorithms but i cant find an exact answer, im a noob though..be gentle..any answers would be a great help..

Answer (score 5):

Not really sure what you're after, but you have to differentiate between *encryption* and *hashing*.

Example Encryption Algorithms:

- DES
- CAST-128
- **Blowfish**
- **Twofish**
- CAST-256

Example Hash Algorithms

- **MD5**
- SHA-1
- SHA-256

Encryption is a reversible process, where you can get back your original data.

Hashing is a one-way process, that can boil all your data down to a 20-byte "*fingerprint*".

---

Just to expand on hashing:

```
          20 MB file
              |
              ˅
         [MD5 hash]
              |
              ˅
0xe57262ce00045e850fd5392073a6e9cd
```

Hashing is *very* different from encryption. If you hash your data you *cannot* get it back.

Imagine hashing is like modulo addition:

```
 37
+69
+28
===
134 mod 10 = 4
```

Or more graphically:

```
      37,69,28
         |
         ˅
[Ian's hash algorithm]
         |
         ˅
         4
```

A hash is used to generate a "*fingerprint*" of your data. It is one way, and not reversible.

Since you are using a "chat" program, i assume you are want to *encrypt* the messages. For that you need an **encryption** algorithm, not a hashing algorithm.

Comment: i evaluated the Md5 encryption algorithm in Lan chat, result shows that in a Lan Chat that i have created using Md5 encryption the lesser the strings that i will sent to the client,, the longer the time it takes while in a larger string, the faster it transmits data..why is that?

Comment: Like Ian said, MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a hash algo. It gives you back a 32 character string regardless how long the target string is and cannot be “unhashed” (you cannot get back the original string). What is probably happening is that because it gives a 32 character hash even for a 1-character string, you are getting a lot of overhead, which causes it to take longer.

Comment: if the Md5 is irreversible..why is it that when i used Md5 for sending encrypted messages to a client pc, the client can still read what i have sent, it means the message that i have sent and encrpyted by the Md5 is decrypted when the client recieves it.. heres the main idea... "Send Message + Encrypt= Decrypt+ recieved.."

Comment: @iDarine: You are mistaken. Edit your original question to include the code you are using.